# Undefined method for friendly_id implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id

This is what my Plan.rb looks like:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users
  has_friendly_id :plan, :use_slug => true

end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

#There is other stuff in here, but I stripped it out for brevity purposes.

  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  has_many :stages
  has_many :uploads
  has_many :comments
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
  belongs_to :plan


end
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
'ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Plan.create(:name => "First_Test", :storage => "100")
NoMethodError: undefined method `plan' for #<Plan:0x00000102b8a2d8>
    /gemms/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing'
    /gemms/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/friendly_id-3.2.0/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb:82:in `slug_text'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/friendly_id-3.2.0/lib/friendly_id/active_record_adapter/slugged_model.rb:49:in `build_a_slug'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `create_or_update'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:39:in `save'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:237:in `block (2 levels) in save'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:204:in `transaction'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:287:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:237:in `block in save'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:248:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:236:in `save'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `create'
    from (irb):3
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    /gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, but I can't create any new 'plans'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your database doesn't have a `plan` column in your `plans` table. In addition to adding the `has_friendly_id` statement to your model, did you create and run a migration to add the `plan` field to your database?

Comment: hrmm....a `plan` column to my `plans` table? Hrmm....something doesn't sound right with that. I actually don't have it, but why would I need a `plan` column in my `plans` table? Then I guess I should be referencing `:plan_id` ?

Comment: Yep -- whatever you specify as `has_friendly_id`, there needs to be a database column with the same name.

Comment: I added a `plans` table and a `plan_id` column to my user's table - if that's what you were referring to. But I am not sure why I would need a `plan` column in my `plans` table.

Comment: Ahh...interesting. Hrmm....that's kinda strange. Ok, I will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: Well if you're going to give something a friendly id, it's gotta be stored somewhere, right? If your `:name` field is unique, you may just want to do `has_friendly_id :name` instead?

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I did. But I guess :name has to always be unique right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error (undefined method `has_friendly_id') if you have upgraded friendly_id from Version 3 to 4.

Command 'has_friendly_id' has been replaced by 'friendly_id' - see how to upgrade here:

http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/file/WhatsNew.md

Note: You'll also need to create a migration to add a new slug column to your table.